# Please revert the change on no longer sub-grouping badges on the [all] tab of badges page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, badges

In the old design, similar badges were grouped together on the badges page for the `all` tab. This is helpful because it is easier to recognize an entire group of badges at a time, and other tabs doesn't group them, which is reasonable.

[image]

However, the new design doesn't have them anymore. Separator bars are present between every single badge. This makes it really annoying to navigate the page.

[image]

Can we PLEASE have it back?

Comment: Oops, yeah this wasn't intentional - taking a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, rolling out in the next 15 minutes.